# Representation of a vector as a sum of two

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

I have vector $\mathbf{g}=(0,2,-1,1)$ and I have to represent the vector as a sum of two $\mathbf{g}_1$ and $\mathbf{g}_2$ if $\mathbf{g}_1 \in L$ and $\mathbf{g}_2 \in L^{\perp}$ if $L = \langle \mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2\rangle \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and if $\mathbf{a}_1=(0,1,1,1)$ and $\mathbf{a}_2=(-1,0,1,0)$

The main problem is that I do not even know how to approach it in theory, what steps I need to reproduce and so on. I have been looking and googling for explanation for some mature amount of time, but still did not get what I supposed to do step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{g}_1$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf g$ onto $L$. Now, define $\mathbf{g}_2=\mathbf{g}-\mathbf{g}_1$. Then $\mathbf{g}_2\in L^\perp$.

It turns out that $\mathbf{g}_1=(-1,1,0,1)$ and that $\mathbf{g}_2=(1,1,-1,0)$.

Comment: Did you mean I have to act like that?

$$\mathbf{g}_1 =\mathrm{proj}_{L}\operatorname{g} = \left(\frac{g,a_1}{a_1,a_1}\right)a_1+\left(\frac{g,a_2}{a_2,a_2}\right)a_2$$

then $$\mathbf{g}_2 = \mathbf{g} - \mathbf{g}_1$$

and then make sure that $\mathbf{g}_2 \in L$

?

Comment: @M.Mass No. That wouldn't work, because $\mathbf{g}_2$ might not belong to $L$. What I did was to apply Gram-Schmidt to $\{a_1,a_2\}$, thus getting an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of $L$; I got $e_1=\frac1{\sqrt3}(0,1,1,1)$ and $e_2=\frac1{\sqrt{15}}(-3,1,-2,1)$. Then I took $\mathbf{g}_1=\langle\mathbf{g},e_1\rangle e_1+\langle\mathbf{g},e_2\rangle e_2$. This always works.

Comment: Just to clarify, is $\langle\mathbf{g},e_1\rangle e_1\ldots$ scalar multiplication here?

Comment: @M.Mass Yes, it is.